# MySQL How do I count the number of occurences of each ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

It may be difficult to explain what I am after, apologies if the question is vague.

I have a table which associates products with keywords using IDs

So I may have product IDs, 2,3,4,5 associated with Keyword id 14
and product IDs 3,6,9 associated with Keyword id 15

My question is How do I count and store the total for those IDs associated with Keyword 14 and for those IDs associated with Keyword 15 and so on (New Keywords added all the time)?

MY SQL so far:

```
select products_keyword_categories.key_cat_name 
from products_keyword_to_product 
inner join products_keyword_categories 
on products_keyword_categories.key_cat_id = products_keyword_to_product.key_cat_id 
group by products_keyword_categories.key_cat_name
```

Many thanks in advance for any advice. Also, if there is any terminology that will aid me in further research via a Google search that would also be most welcome.

Edit to add: In the example above the table containing the associations is products_keyword_to_product - I inner join the other table to return the Keyword name.

Edit to add (2): Sorry I was afraid my question would be vague.
If I wanted to just count all the products using keyword ID 14 I would use COUNT() AS - As mentioned in the answers but I also need to count the number of products using Keyword ID 15 and Keyword ID 16 etc. - Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: could you give your table structure with some explanations, and maybe sample datas ? your table names are not that clear at my poor eyes.

Comment: Assuming your products_keyword_to_product table is a standard lookup table and therefore contains the keyword_id and the product_id fields, why not just use: 'select keyword_id, count(*) as num_products from products_keyword_to_product group by keyword_id? The will give you the number of products that have a particular keyword.

Comment: products_keyword_to_product is a table which stores Keyword IDs and the Product IDs using that keyword. So Product A(ID 1) uses Keyword A(ID 14), Product B(ID 2) also uses Keyword A(ID 14) - Hope that clarifies.
The Table names used were to fit in with an existing schema so they are a bit long-winded I'm afraid!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select key_cat_name ,count(*) 
from products_keyword_categories pkc 
    inner join products_keyword_to_product ptk on pkc.id=ptk.key_id 
group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select cat.key_cat_name, count(*) from
products_keyword_categories cat inner join products_keyword_to_product prod
on prod.key_cat_id=cat.key_cat_id
group by cat.key_cat_name
```

**Edit:**

```
select cat.key_cat_name, prod_assoc.product_id, count(*) from
products_keyword_categories cat inner join products_keyword_to_product prod_assoc
on prod_assoc.key_cat_id=cat.key_cat_id
group by cat.key_cat_name,prod_assoc.product_id
```

Assuming your tables structure is like this:

**products_keyword_categories**

```
key_cat_id key_cat_name

1          Electronics

2          Toys

3          Software
```

**products_keyword_to_product**

```
key_cat_id  product_id

1           1 

2           1

3           2

1           2
```

**products**

```
product_id name

1          Product A

2          Robot
```

**Edit 2:**

Try this

```
SELECT key_cat_name, product_id, COUNT(*)
FROM
(select cat.key_cat_name, prod_assoc.product_id from
products_keyword_categories cat inner join products_keyword_to_product prod_assoc
on prod_assoc.key_cat_id=cat.key_cat_id) as tbl
GROUP BY key_cat_name, product_id
```

**Edit 3:**

The query above is made of 2 parts:

The inner part:

```
(select cat.key_cat_name, prod_assoc.product_id from
products_keyword_categories cat inner join products_keyword_to_product prod_assoc
on prod_assoc.key_cat_id=cat.key_cat_id)
```

Which gives 1 row per combination of product_id and key_cat_name.

The outer part:

```
SELECT key_cat_name, product_id, COUNT(*)
FROM (...) as tbl
GROUP BY key_cat_name, product_id
```

Which operates on the results of the inner part (as tbl), counting how many times a combination of key_cat_name and product_id appears on the inner part.

Check this: [Subqueries in MySQL, Part 1](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/subqueries_part_1.html)

Comment: Hi Nathan, Adding count(*) to the SQL results in only one row with a count of 10 whereas I need all of the rows to display with a total amount of usages (Currently there are 10 rows).

Comment: I'm afraid what you have produced here is a little beyond my current understanding. It appears that you are creating and using aliases which is something I've never touched on before. Sorry for my ignorance. Could you dumb it down?

Comment: @Andrew, yes, I'm using aliases. I've edited my answer explaining that. Also, there's a link on the topic http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/subqueries_part_1.html

Comment: thanks for your new response. I still can't make it work at this point but I thank you for the further reading and taking the time to break it down for me. I'm sure after a bit more investigation it will 'click'.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you just need to add the following:

select count(products_keyword_to_product.id), products_keyword_categories.key_cat_name
...
the rest is correct

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), reference_field FROM table WHERE...
HAVING field=value
GROUP BY field
```

For aggregate conditions you must use `HAVING`

Comment: Thanks for updating this. I obviously will need to read about using 'HAVING' as it's something totally new to me. Thanks again.

Comment: np, my answer has any vote but i think is the way to do this. At first can be a little ofuscated try to learn it but then it's a powerful syntax